# Can't create encrypted partitions during Debian installation

Tags: debian, system-installation, encryption

I am using debian 7.4  cd.
When I set a partition as '/' during manual partition. It is fine.
However when I then try to use it as 'physical volume for encryption'...everything works fine it erases and writes random data BUT THEN mount point '/' disappears!
.
And when I try to proceed with installation,it says
"NO root file system is defined.Please correct this from partitioning menu"

And when I try to make '/', I cant modify the partition to be used as '/' because it says-"No modification can be made.In use as physical volume for encrypted volume"

I am following these instructions:http://www.debianuserforums.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=460

Answer (score 0):

line one of the install guide you linked to states

"
This guide describes and mostly shows with pictures the steps involved in creating encrypted partitions with the Debian installer. The partitioning scheme is to have a small /boot partition, which is not encrypted, and separate / and /home partitions which are encrypted. 
"

The unencrypted process for partitions has these partitions, '/' '/usr' '/tmp' '/home' '/var' the '/' root partition is set to boot but when you encrypt the partition you then need the unencrypted boot partition because in order to decrypt the root partition and other usual partitions you need to the unencrypted boot partition to decrypt the root partition.

If you do not setup an LVM for each of your partitions /usr /tmp and encrypt them, the installer will not realise the mount points have been set and fail, this guide lists that step

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40638984/how_to_lvm_debian_wheezy.pdf

Comment: The above document link advises a root partition size of 150mb.  This is too small and will cause the grub setup/install to fail. The actual size of the complete grub install is 255mb.

Comment: provided link is down